# Array list "get" issues

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, combobox

In this class I'm getting the names of a list of bus stop stored in a database, and I'd like to show them into a combo box. But i get the following error:

The method get(int) in the type ArrayList is not applicable for the arguments (String)

Any suggestions?

```
// gets the stop names from the database
    int[] routeArray = BusStopInfo.getRoutes();
    int[] stopIdArray;
    ArrayList<String>stopName = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int i = 0; i < routeArray.length; i++) {
        stopIdArray = BusStopInfo.getBusStops(i);
        for (int j = 0; j < stopIdArray.length; j++) {
            stopName.add(BusStopInfo.getFullName(stopIdArray[j]));
        }//for
    } // for
    String[] nameArray = new String[stopName.size()];
    nameArray = stopName.toArray(nameArray);
    for (int k = 0; k < stopIdArray.length; k++){
        stopListDeparture = stopName.get(nameArray[k]);
    }

    stopListDeparture.setSelectedIndex(0);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(stopListDeparture, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```

Comment: Try `String str = (String) stopName.get(k);`

Comment: Use `Map` for storing

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE/MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for Swing GUI in local variables

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go out on a limb with a different suggestion from the other answers. Consider these lines:

```
nameArray = stopName.toArray(nameArray);
for (int k = 0; k < stopIdArray.length; k++){
    stopListDeparture = stopName.get(nameArray[k]);
}
```

You are converting a list, `stopName` into an array of `String` and then iterating through that array and getting the item in that array that ... corresponds to itself? Are you sure that's what you mean?

Instead of `stopName.get(nameArray[k])` I think perhaps instead you mean `stopName.get(stopIdArray[k])`. Unlike `nameArray`, `stopIdArray` is in fact an array of `int`s, so this would compile and run just fine.

The giveaway here is that you are iterating from 0 to the length of `stopIdArray` but instead are getting elements from a different array (`nameArray`). Sometimes this is what you mean to do, but often it's a code smell.

Comment: +1, I was just writing something akin to this but you beat me to it. The `ArrayList` being copied into an array seems rather redundant.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `stopName.get(nameArray[k]);`, nameArray[k] is a `String`. You need to do `stopName.get(Integer.parseInt(nameArray[k]));`

Comment: Although if that is the case, I would change the name of `nameArray` since I would expect that to be an array of names, and names aren't (usually) numbers...

Comment: Totally agreed. but `stopName` is not a great variable name either ;).

Answer (score 0):

Ur problem is in below line

```
stopListDeparture = stopName.get(nameArray[k]);
```

nameArray[k] returns a string and you are trying to retrieve one specific element from a list using that. As per the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) get method takes an int and returns the element at the specified position in that list.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way of doing it. I'm declaring the JComboBox as a .
Thanks everyone for your answers.

```
JComboBox<String> stopListDeparture = new JComboBox<String>();

    int[] routeArray = BusStopInfo.getRoutes();
    int[] stopIdArray = new int[0];
    ArrayList<String>stopName = new ArrayList<String>();

    for(int i = 0; i < routeArray.length; i++) {
        stopIdArray = BusStopInfo.getBusStops(routeArray[i]);
        for (int j = 0; j < stopIdArray.length; j++) {
            stopName.add(BusStopInfo.getFullName(stopIdArray[j]));
        }//for
    } // for
    String[] nameArray = stopName.toArray(new String[stopName.size()]);
    nameArray = stopName.toArray(nameArray);
    for (int k = 0; k < stopIdArray.length; k++){
        stopListDeparture = new JComboBox<String>(nameArray);
    }

    stopListDeparture.setSelectedIndex(0);
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    add(stopListDeparture, BorderLayout.NORTH);
```